# How to copy content of asset folder to sdcard?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to copy files in 'assets' to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)

Is there any way to copy the content of the asset folder with all the directories, subdirectories, and files to the sdcard?

Comment: There shouldn't way to copy asset folder w/sub dirs, at least not everything can be copied. Android would compress/pre-process some types of content and I really doubt if they were kept in their original form. For example, strings would be compiled, some layouts (menus) may processed in a way not in xml format. They simply, not present in the final apk file.

Comment: xandy I am not talking about the res folder, I meant the assets which is untouched by the android system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much, just use standard java I/O. However, you pretty much have to know your asset contents ahead of time and code to them, as the `list()` method on `AssetManager` is not terribly sophisticated.

Comment: I was trying to use Apache FileUtils, it has some handy methods to copy full directories, but I cannot make it work with the assets.

Comment: @biquillo: I really doubt Apache FileUtils will help you here.

Comment: ok got it :) I think the best solution for copying lots of files such in my case is to zip everything put it in the assets folder and then uncompress it to the sdcard :) thanks anyway :)